# Is there anything in the Bible that suggests joy in Heaven is greater than best of Earthly joy?

Tags: biblical-basis, heaven

Writer Randy Alcorn suggests we CAN imagine Heaven. In fairness to his viewpoint the 'Eye hath not seen nor ears heard..." quote from Corintheans (if fully read through) does NOT mean we cannot contemplate the afterlife.
I prefer the seemingly widespread notion that the happiness of Heaven is immeasurably greater than even the greatest happiness here. But WHERE is there anything suggestive of this in the Bible itself?! It seems utterly 'added on' by us!

Comment: I suggest that this question be considered the main one for Thomas Jennings' questions on this topic: [Is the idea that the pleasures we experience now are mild foretastes of Heaven Biblical?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/24408)